# Assertion failure Custom Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to work with Edge Swipe Demonstration classes made by Robert Ryan 
https://github.com/robertmryan/edge-swipe-demonstration

While using it when I changed the firstviewcontroller with the newcontroller which I made
its showing me error at the NSAssert line

Here is the EdgeSwipeSegue.m code

```
@implementation EdgeSwipeSegue

- (void)perform
{
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    id <ParentControllerDelegate>parent = (id)source.parentViewController;
    if(parent==nil){
        NSLog(@"Parent is nil");
    }

    NSAssert([parent conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ParentControllerDelegate)], @"Parent does not conform to ParentControllerDelegate; parent = %@", parent);

    [parent pushChildViewController:self.destinationViewController];
}
```

I have BarButton to which I drag to the secondviewcontroller and selected the edgeSegue but maybe I am missing something

Why do the assertion fail ??

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
// I assume that you have NewViewController

// in NewViewController.h
@interface NewViewController : UIViewController < ParentControllerDelegate >

//in NewViewController.m : just implement method is declared in ParentControllerDelegate
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out valuable time... but I understood where I was going wrong. .I have posted my answer ... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

OK I found it by own here's the answer

I had this hirearchy

```
 - ParentViewController(ContainerView)
   - NavigationController
     - Viewcontroller
```

So this id parent = (id)source.parentViewController; was giving me navigationviewcontroller instead of the parentviewcontroller which was my required

so solved it like this

```
UIViewcontroller *cont = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *source = con.navigationController;
```

and it worked